# Overlaying caron and a vowel in boldface and italic styles

Tags: fonts, accents, bold, overlays, italic

I found that a lovely typeface I wanted to use did not contain the graphs **ǎ ě ǐ ǒ ǔ ǚ**, which I need for Pinyin romanization in text mode. Discussion below takes **ǎ** as the example.

Using the graph `ǎ` as literal text or as its Unicode codepoint `^^^^01ce` produces a blank; the normal caron-composition macro `\v{a}` etc. also produces a blank. Surely all three cases come about because the typeface lacks a glyph for the composite graph.

The glyph for `\textasciicaron` alone does exist in the font:

[image: caron Gyre Termes]

and I can create a passable rendering of **ǎ** manually using

```
`\rlap{\textasciicaron}\kern.7pt a` :
```

[image: ǎ normal Gyre Termes]

The problem is that it does not render correctly either in boldface or italics (kerning adjusted to .1pt on the latter):

[image: ǎ boldface Gyre Termes] and [image: ǎ italic Gyre Termes]

I suppose that is because the `\textasciicaron`, either alone or overlaid, is not affected by those processes, at least not in standard syntax. `FakeSlant` and `FakeBold` similarly have no effect on `\textasciicaron`.

Can anyone suggest another line of attack to get these glyphs in bold and italic?

---

**EDIT**: My original posting concerned the font TeX Gyre Termes; shortly after posting, I realized that my version of the font was out of date and the new version has the glyphs I was discussing. So I have removed discussion of the font but left my question, since I think it is a valid one that I was unable to solve on my own.

Answer (score 3):

Example in Plain with XeTeX:

```
\font\termes="TeX Gyre Termes"
\font\bftermes="TeX Gyre Termes/B"
\font\ittermes="TeX Gyre Termes/I"
\def\caron#1{{\accent"02C7 #1}}
\termes
W\caron ass\caron{a}p?
\bftermes
W\caron ass\caron{a}p?
\ittermes
W\caron ass\caron{a}p?
\bye
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Argh! I took a look at the date of my copy of TeX Gyre Termes and found it was 2008 (v. 1.103); the current version of the font is 2009 (v.2.004). And the graphs I was discussing are now there. So the problem remains as a general one but not for TeX Gyre Termes. I'll edit the post to reflect that.